# Read stdout and stderr logs from selenium controlled chrome browser

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I made some minor modifications to the Chromium browser and built a custom version that does some logging on stderr. I would like to control this browser with Selenium (Python version) and read these stderr logs.

The following is a minimal example of what I am doing:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os.path    

options = Options()
options.binary_location = '/home/phani/chromium/src/out/Default/chrome'
options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=/tmp/')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.abspath("chromedriver"), chrome_options=options)
driver.get('http://www.facebook.com')
```

Can someone tell me how I can read the logs produced by the Chromium browser? For Firefox, there is an argument called "log_file" which allows us to direct output from the browser to stdout/stderr if we prefer. 
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_firefox/selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary.html#module-selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary

Is there something similar for Chromium?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/logging

Comment: @PixelEinstein Yes, this definitely covers what I need. I will be glad to accept it if you  can post that as an answer. For my particular use case, I didn't need this, as there is a way to direct logs from headless chrome to a specific file. https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/headless-dev/A_-EpJkuLvk

Comment: great, glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes,

In Chrome you can pass the logging as a parameter like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="Path\\to\\your\\chromedriver", service_args=["--verbose", "--log-path=C:\\path\\to\\log"])
```

Where the `--verbose` creates verbose logging instead of just errors, and `--log-path` is a filepath in case you want to write out the log to file.

The logging documentation for *Chrome* is [HERE](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/logging)

As per you comment, you can get information on **headless logging** [HERE](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/headless-dev/A_-EpJkuLvk).